# How to pass props within components with react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm struggling to pass props between components with **react-rouer v6**

Here is the routes in App.tsx, I want to pass props from the component (Home) which redirect to this one (EditUser)

```
<Routes>
    <Route path={ROUTES.HOME} element={<Home />} />
    <Route path={ROUTES.EDIT_USER} element={<EditUser props />} />
</Routes>
```

The home page have some functionality to render a table with users

Here is the function to navigate to the EditUser page to be able to edit
I want to be able to pass one of the users once the button "edit" is clicked
*(I added the state since I read that was the way to acces from the Edit User page)*

```
  const handleEdit = (user: IUser) => {
    navigate(ROUTES.EDIT_USER, {
      state: {
        user,
      },
    });
  };
```

The edit button *(Redirection is working It's just the fact to pass that user from components)*

```
<EditButton
   data-testid={`edit-button-${user.id}`}
   text={ES.common.edit}
   onClick={() => {
      handleEdit(user);
   }}
   ></EditButton>
```

Any idea?

As always, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send state in the route transition it isn't sent via props, but rather it's sent via the routing context. In the `EditUser` component you can access the sent route state via the `location` object returned from the `useLocation` hook.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const location = useLocation();
const { state } = location;
const { user } = state || {};
```

Comment: Also, since state has unknown type, I would have to cast that user as Object I guess

Comment: @Sergio18rg Yes, if you are using Typescript then you'll likely want/need to type the state value being destructured.